# How to rerun the SSIS package after sometime if download of files failed?

Tags: ssis, ssms, business-intelligence, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have one SQL Job which calls one SSIS package to download and load files to Data warehouse. I have scheduled this job at 9 AM in the morning. But sometime happens that the files are not available on FTP server so 9 AM schedule gets fail and so the job gets fail.

I want to rerun the Job automatically after the files are available on FTP server. Even I don't want to fail the job if files are not available on FTP. So the basic requirement is to rerun the job automatically if the download component fails due to unavailability of files.

Comment: If you look at the advanced pane in the step properties, you'll see the solution immediately.

Comment: I already tried it, but I'm not aware of the timing when the files get available. I added 5 retrieve attempts and 30 Minutes interval. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Seems like the problem isn't the agent step and the lack of consistency of when the files are available; that's what you need to fix. That or run you agent job much later in the day, when you know the file will definitely be there.

Comment: If you dotn know when the file will be delivered exactly, schedule the job to run every 10 min for 3 hours or something.  IF your job checks if file exists, and if not, does nothing,  Then if it does exist does processing.  Then re-running multiple times wont be a problem.  So if no file exists, do not fail job, just exit and next time it runs it will pick it up.

Comment: In this scenario, even if the file get loaded at particular time then how we can stop next processing schedules which will happens in every 10 mins ?